# XSRF-TOKEN not being sent By Angular 2 as it says it will do by default

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, csrf-protection

My Login request's response looks like this as given below:-

- It has the Cookie JSESSIONID and XSRF-TOKEN

[image]

Now the other subsequent request looks like as follows. I read that Angular 2 by default takes the value from the cookie and attached to the header for every subsequent request but its not doing that.

[image]

Please let me know what should I do so that Angular takes it up automatically and globally.

CORS SETUP

```
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Comment: Please add your CORS setup configuration.

Comment: @lin is there something to do with CORS. I will pull that up. Just a min

Comment: @lin Done. I did put up the CORS setting

Comment: Oh well sorry. This is not about CORS. I was wrong. But why is your sever responding 403 forbidden?

Comment: @lin Since there is no XSRF-TOKEN in the request so that backend forbids.

Comment: Thats why Iam wondering. The cookie is setup in your request. `Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=9796ef...`

Comment: @lin yes its there but it does not travel as X-XSRF-TOKEN. I am stuck because of this.

Comment: You should add allow `X-XSRF-TOKEN` Header to your CORS setup, thats for sure. Else the client/server will ignores those headers and kick it out of the request. Stupid guides in the internet ...

Comment: @lin Its not at all sending the Token in the request. If that sends we can get a CORS error. But as such there is nothing in the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135153/discussion-between-lin-and-shiv-kumar-ganesh).

Answer (score 1):

You are making a GET Request and expecting XSRF Token

> By default, an interceptor sends this cookie on all mutating requests
>   (POST, etc.) to relative URLs but not on GET/HEAD requests or on
>   requests with an absolute URL.

https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection